# CompilerError: Stack too deep, try removing local variables. How to solve the problem?

Tags: solidity

I'm having problems with this part of the code. Can you tell me how to solve this problem? I have read various documentation, but maybe someone knows the solution

```
  function _getValues(uint256 tAmount) private view returns (uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256 ) {
        (uint256 tFee, uint256 tBurn, uint256 tCharity, uint256 tLiquidity) = _getTBasics(tAmount, _TAX_FEE, _BURN_FEE, _CHARITY_FEE, _LIQUIDITY_FEE);
        uint256 tTransferAmount = getTTransferAmount(tAmount, tFee, tBurn, tCharity, tLiquidity);
        uint256 currentRate =  _getRate();
        (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rFee) = _getRBasics(tAmount, tFee, currentRate);
        uint256 rTransferAmount = _getRTransferAmount(rAmount, rFee, tBurn, tCharity, tLiquidity, currentRate);
        return (rAmount, rTransferAmount, rFee, tTransferAmount, tFee, tBurn, tCharity, tLiquidity);
    }
```

Comment: I don't know the exact answer, but my guess would be the sausage code you have here `(uint256 tFee, uint256 tBurn, uint256 tCharity, uint256 tLiquidity)`. Here's a link that might give you an idea:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61619191/internalcompilererror-stack-too-deep-try-using-fewer-variables

Answer (score 0):

you can try a method that was used in one of the Uniswap router here: [Uniswap](https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-periphery/blob/69617118cda519dab608898d62aaa79877a61004/contracts/UniswapV2Router02.sol#L327-L333)

or an article by James Carlyle [James Carlyle](https://web.archive.org/web/20161015173410/http://james.carlyle.space/2015/07/22/solidity-stack-too-deep/)

you might need to do a lot of refactoring if you are to use a struct